# Error in an XML file: aborting build. on android

Tags: android, xml, building

i have a problem when building android project.

i build android project and i get an error. the error is : "Error in an XML file: aborting build.".i tried all solution.

- I deleted main.out.xml. After that, i cleaned up the project. But it didn't work
- There is no error in xml file
- I deleted bin folder. It worked at first. But when i change anything in xml file, i get same error

My xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">


    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Telefon numarası :"
        />     
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/txtPhoneNo"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        />
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:text="Mesaj :"
        />     

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="@string/txtMessage" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSendSMS"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnSendSMS" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks Padma Kumar. it worked.

Comment: "Gamecat is toon krijthe", why did you edit my question ? there is no error or something like that. that is meaningless:/

Comment: Make a backup of the project. Delete it from eclipse. Import it using 'Existing Projects into Workspace' and NOT 'Existing Android code into Workspace'

Comment: @PadmaKumar: I restarted my eclipse but it's still giving me the same error ..

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your xml filename as small letter and don't use number. Use only dot eg main.xml.
After create xml right click >Source>Format. Run your application good luck.

Comment: v.good tip .. still not working for me